# An inequality relating the Kullback-Leibler divergence of two discrete distributions with constant reference distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, entropy

Suppose that $D_{KL}(p_1\parallel q)<1$ and $D_{KL}(p_2\parallel q)<1$. I'm trying to show that either $D_{KL}(p_1\parallel p_2)$ or $D_{KL}(p_2\parallel p_1)$ will have an upper bound close to 1 provided ${q}$ is fixed. It seems intuitive that if $p_1$ and $q$ are similar enough and if $p_2$ and $q$ are also similar enough then $p_2$ can reasonably approximate $p_1$ or vice versa. Is this actually true?

Comment: What do you mean by "close to 1"?

Comment: @losif Pinelis, I mean the bound should be finite and small

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., let $p_1,p_2,q$ be pdf's on $[0,1]$ such that $q=1$, $p_1=\frac1{1-h}\,1_{[0,1-h]}$, and $p_2=\frac1{1-h}\,1_{[h,1]}$, for some $h\in(0,1)$. Then
$$D_{KL}(p_1\parallel q)=D_{KL}(p_2\parallel q)=\ln\frac1{1-h}\to0$$
as $h\downarrow0$, whereas
$$D_{KL}(p_1\parallel p_2)=D_{KL}(p_2\parallel p_1)=\infty$$
for all $h\in(0,1)$.

Comment: This is a nice counterexample, which emphasizes that KL is neither symmetric nor does it satisfy the triangle inequality.  Nonetheless, sometimes for special classes of distributions, a weak form of the triangle inequality holds (see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.05485.pdf ).

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee : Thank you for the reference.